# Overwrite injected CSS from AdBlock

Tags: css, adblock, operator-precedence

my site displays a buy link which is affiliated with the Awin affiliation program. Awin links are blocked by AdBlock Plus via this CSS which is injected by the extension :

```
a[href^="https://www.awin1.com/cread.php?"] {
    display: none!important;
}
```

I tried to overwrite that with Javascript by detecting if the user is using AdBlock : in that case I add a `.ab` class to the  and  tags and and declares this CSS rule inmy stylesheet :

```
html.ab {
    a[href^="https://www.awin1.com/cread.php?"].ab {
        display: block!important;
    }
}
```

But this does not work. 
Does injected CSS by extensions take precedence over the app's stylesheet, whatever my rules ?

thanks

Comment: Hi Maxime, may be this helps: I had the same problem, and detected that I was using a suspicious className on some elements. I changed btn-ad for btn-other and Adblocker stopped blocking that elements

Comment: regarding precedence of CSS rules, yes, adblock rules come with display none !important, before my own rules, so, this took no effect.